# update multiple rows with checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

Created a gridview that should allow the used to check a checkbox beside each record in a gridview. After selecting the checkbox they can select a button that should change each status of the checked record. The code below does the updating if i check 1 or 2 rows but error if i try to update all records at once.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewwork" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcework" Width="90%" ShowFooter="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridViewwork_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    DataKeyNames="WorkID" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="2" GridLines="None">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
```

```
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>

               <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxcomplete" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DIAS Employee" SortExpression="employee">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="employee_txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("employee") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("employee") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>

        <asp:Button ID="btSubmit" runat="server" Text="Mark as Complete" onclick=" btButton_Click"></asp:Button>

        </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Number" SortExpression="filenumber">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="filenumber_txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("filenumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("filenumber") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" SortExpression="action">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="action_txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("action") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("action") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="workdate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="workdate_txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("workdate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("workdate") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks" SortExpression="remarks">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="remarks_txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("remarks") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("remarks") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
```

Code behind

```
protected void btButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewwork.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkUpdate = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBoxcomplete");
        if (chkUpdate.Checked)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlcon = <my connection.
            string query = "Update WorkFlowActivity set completedate=@completedate, workstatus=@workstatus where WorkID = @WorkID";
            SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);

            sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@completedate", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workstatus", "Yes");
            sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkID", GridViewwork.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
            sqlcon.Open();
            try
            {
                sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                GridViewwork.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            sqlcon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to update all records at once I get 
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

This is on the line that I add the parameter @WorkID. Really not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Could you also include the full definition for the GridView?

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridViewwork" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcework" Width="90%" ShowFooter="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridViewwork_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        DataKeyNames="WorkID" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="2" GridLines="None">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please update your question with the `GridView` definition.

Answer (score -1):

Collection of grid view rows are all the rows along with data rows (including header, footer, etc)

In order for you to over come it, you need to check the index of the row not be -1 while fetching data from the GridView row. Something like;

```
if(row.RowIndex != -1)
    string dataValue = row["columnName"].ToString();
```

In your case, you need to get this done before you are fetching the checkbox control from the row.

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding..!!

Nayan

Comment: This is also incorrect. GridView.Rows only contains rows have a RowType of DataRow. A filter for other DataControlRowTypes is only necessary in the RowDataBound event, where all rows are affected.